# Zonal statistics on raster layers that intersect line

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, overlay, zonal-statistics

I have a line feature class of routes and a raster file with 12 unique values. I want to know how much cells of each value in the raster has that intersect with lines.

I've tried zonal statistics (as table) but the result is the opposite, I get the mean value of the raster file within each line. My needed output however is a table with in the first collumn the raster values 1 to 12 and in the second column the total area of that value that intersects with lines.

Is there any function that does this for lines in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: rasterstats (Python package) will return an array where all pixels are masked except the intersecting ones; it is only a couple lines of code to create your table following that. As for an ArcGIS solution, I don't know. You might look at a profile tool, which should somehow fetch the values along the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Tabulate Areas tool. [Link to Tool Description here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/tabulate-area.htm)

Comment: It doesn't look like that will take a line feature as an input, unless I'm missing something. OP would need to rasterize the line first.

Comment: From the link: if a point or line is used as the input raster or feature class data, the area intersected by those features will be reported.